# How to send data in multiple db tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have created web api 2 project which created a local db in which there was a table "AspNetUser". I have merged those tables with my own db. In my database I have a table "Employee Information" that will store all information of the employee except his Email,Password and UserName and all the other information will be stored in "Employee Information" table.

This is the pre-written code to register user:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email};

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);

                var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, model.SelectedRole);


            }
            else if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

And This is my own logic to register User:

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(EmployeeInformation))]
        [ActionName("EmployeeInfo")]
        [DeflateCompression]
        public IHttpActionResult PostEmployeeInformation(EmployeeInformation EmployeeInfo)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.EmployeeInformations.Add(EmployeeInfo);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

So how can I Store Email,password and Username in "AspNetUser" table and all the other information(name,fathername,dob etc) in "EmployeeInformation" table.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add relation between `ApplicationUser` and `EmployeeInformation` entities:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // other properties

    public int EmployeeInformationID {get;set;}
    public virtual EmployeeInformation EmployeeInformation {get;set;}
}
```

Do same for `EmployeeInformation` class

```
public class EmployeeInformation
{
    // other properties

    public string UserID {get;set;}
    public virtual ApplicationUser User {get;set;}
}
```

Now you have seprate class for user's extra information for example you could write:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostEmployeeInformation(EmployeeInformation employeeInfo)
{
    employeeInfo.UserID="your desired user id, current user id for example";
    db.EmployeeInformations.Add(employeeInfo);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to ask one more thing I already have a UserID field in my "Employee Information" table that will store the ID of User from "AspNetUser" table, so do I need to add all this code or is there any other way by which I can get the ID of the user from Register method of Account Controller and use that id in "PostEmployeeInformation" method to store the remaining information. Thanks.

Comment: You could get all extra data from the register action instead of using a separate method. But if you want to do so you could get current user id by calling `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method. Simply force your users to login before calling this method.